# Why am I getting the following error with eslint (expected "ident" or "string", got "return")

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, vue.js, eslint

I am getting the following error from `eslint`, but I can't see anything wrong with my code. Does anyone know what the problem is and how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Are you using webpack? Was this file loaded by `vue-loader` first? The syntax looks correct to me. Are you sure it is an error from eslint and not something else? Have you tried deleting that code and typing it out again (in case there is some weird unicode character in there)? This might be caused by another issue that isn't immediately obvious. Show us your webpack config.